# how to get postdata(password) in controller from phtml by submitting form

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, password

```
$password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');
$passwordConfirmation = $this->getRequest()->getParam('confirmation');
```

> **custom.xml**

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_resetpassword>
```

> **resetforgottenpassword.phtml**

```
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/resetpasswordpost/id/'.$this->getCustomerId().'/token/'.$this->getResetPasswordLinkToken()); ?>" id="form-validate" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
    <div class="fieldset" style="margin-top: 70px;">
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('New Password'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" name="resetpassword[password]" id="password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm New Password'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" name="resetpassword[cpassword]" id="confirmation" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields'); ?></p>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Reset a Password')); ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Reset a Password'); ?></span></span></button>

    </div>
</form>
```

> **AccountController.php**

```
    public function resetPasswordPostAction()
    {


       $customerId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $resetPasswordLinkToken = (string) $this->getRequest()->getparam('token');
        try 
        {
         $this->_validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken);
         } 
         catch (Exception $exception) 
         {

            $this->_getSession()->addError( $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $password = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');

        $passwordConfirmation = $this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation');

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($password);
        print_r($passwordConfirmation);
        exit;
        if (iconv_strlen($password) <= 0) {
            array_push($errorMessages, $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('New password field cannot be empty.'));
        }
        /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
        $customer = $this->_getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

        $customer->setPassword($password);
        $customer->setPasswordConfirmation($passwordConfirmation);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($customer->getData());

        $validationErrorMessages = $customer->validate();
        if (is_array($validationErrorMessages)) {
            $errorMessages = array_merge($errorMessages, $validationErrorMessages);
        }

        if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
            $this->_getSession()->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            foreach ($errorMessages as $errorMessage) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($errorMessage);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/resetpassword', array(
                'id' => $customerId,
               'token' => $resetPasswordLinkToken
            ));
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Empty current reset password token i.e. invalidate it
            $customer->setRpToken(null);
            $customer->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
            $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
            $customer->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess( $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password has been updated.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/login');
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($exception, $this->__('Cannot save a new password.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/resetpassword', array(
                'id' => $customerId,
                'token' => $resetPasswordLinkToken
            ));
            return;
        }
    }
 //  $y=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
       //$t= $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key');

        //$resetpassword = $this->getRequest()->getPost('resetpassword');

       $customerId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $resetPasswordLinkToken = (string) $this->getRequest()->getparam('token');
        try 
        {
         $this->_validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken);
         } 
         catch (Exception $exception) 
         {

            $this->_getSession()->addError( $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $password = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');

        $passwordConfirmation = $this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation');

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($password);
        print_r($passwordConfirmation);
        exit;
        if (iconv_strlen($password) <= 0) {
            array_push($errorMessages, $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('New password field cannot be empty.'));
        }
        /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
        $customer = $this->_getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

        $customer->setPassword($password);
        $customer->setPasswordConfirmation($passwordConfirmation);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($customer->getData());

        $validationErrorMessages = $customer->validate();
        if (is_array($validationErrorMessages)) {
            $errorMessages = array_merge($errorMessages, $validationErrorMessages);
        }

        if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
            $this->_getSession()->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            foreach ($errorMessages as $errorMessage) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($errorMessage);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/resetpassword', array(
                'id' => $customerId,
               'token' => $resetPasswordLinkToken
            ));
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Empty current reset password token i.e. invalidate it
            $customer->setRpToken(null);
            $customer->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
            $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
            $customer->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess( $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password has been updated.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/login');
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($exception, $this->__('Cannot save a new password.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/resetpassword', array(
                'id' => $customerId,
                'token' => $resetPasswordLinkToken
            ));
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get post values in controller like as below. Please use HTML element name attribute to get elements post value, not element Id.

```
$resetPassword = $this->getRequest()->getParam('resetpassword');
if(is_array($resetPassword)) {
   $password = $resetPassword['password'];
   $cpassword = $resetPassword['cpassword'];
}
```